# Splitting values in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Hash in the following format:

```
{"PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b"], "Amount"=>"[\"10000.000\", \"2374.000\"]"}
```

When I write this data into an excel get the following output.

[image]
I want to write the data into the Excel this way:

```
PPS_Id                                     Amount
fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548       10000.000
6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b       2374.000
```

How do I convert my current Hash to the below?

```
{PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548","Amount"=>"10000.000"},{PPS_Id"=>["6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b","Amount"=>"2374.000"}
```

Can you please assist.

Comment: You need an "Excel" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify your original hash from

```
hash = {"PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b"], "Amount"=>"[\"10000.000\", \"2374.000\"]"}
```

to

```
hash = {"PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b"], "Amount"=>["10000.000", "2374.000"]}
```

Note: the last value in the hash is an `Array` instead of a `String`.

Then, you can generate an Array of hashes on which you can iterate to fill your excel:

```
ary = hash.inject([]) do |r, (key, value)|
  value.each_with_index do |e, i|
    r[i] ||= {}
    r[i][key] = e
  end
  r
end

ary     # [{"PPS_Id"=>"fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "Amount"=>"10000.000"}, {"PPS_Id"=>"6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b", "Amount"=>"2374.000"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your hash really looks like this :

```
hash = {"PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b"],
        "Amount"=>"[\"10000.000\", \"2374.000\"]"}
```

you can use scan to parse the floats first :

```
hash["Amount"] = hash["Amount"].scan(/[\d\-\.]+/)
```

Your hash will now look like :

```
{"PPS_Id"=>["fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548", "6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b"],
 "Amount"=>["10000.000", "2374.000"]}
```

To get the table you want, you could just [transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) the hash values :

```
hash.values_at("PPS_Id", "Amount").transpose.each{|id, amount|
  puts format("%s\t%.3f", id, amount)
}
```

It will output :

```
fe4d7c06-215a-48a7-966d-19ab58976548    10000.000
6e90208e-4ab2-4d44-bbaa-9a874bff095b    2374.000
```